# Javascript tablesort doesn't work for dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html file:

```
 <html>
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.ru/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.ru/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
        $("#excelDataTable1").tablesorter(); 
        } 
        ); 
        </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="main()">
    <table id="excelDataTable" border="1" class="tablesorter">
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the script.js

```
var myList=[{"Идентификатор" : "1", "Название" : "Iphone","Стоимость":"500","Количество":"5"},
        {"Идентификатор" : "2", "Название" : "XBOX","Стоимость":"300","Количество":"7"},
        {"Идентификатор" : "3", "Название" : "XBOX","Стоимость":"400","Количество":"7"}];
function buildHtmlTable() {
 var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

 for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
     var row$ = $('<tr/>');
     for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
         var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

         if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

         row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
     }
    $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
 }

    $("#excelDataTable").append($('<tbody/>'));}
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
{
 var columnSet = [];
 var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

     var rowHash = myList[0];
     for (var key in rowHash) {

         if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
             headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
             columnSet.push(key);
         }
     }
 $("#excelDataTable").append($('<thead/>').html(headerTr$));
 alert(columnSet);
 return columnSet;}
  function main(){
buildHtmlTable();}
```

I used tablesort of jquery to sort the my excelDataTable. When I use generated code of table and paste to the html it works fine, but it doesn't work when I use dynamic table.

Comment: You should call the tablesorter plugin AFTER you have appended the table to the DOM.  Calling it onload, the table probably has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above, you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $.when( main() ).done( function() {
    $("#excelDataTable1").tablesorter(); 
  });
});
```

Information on the `when` method here :  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Basically, this makes certain that your `main()` function has completed before executing the `tablesorter` plugin.

Comment: ha:)
Thank you) so easy

Comment: but.. one thing
after adding this code my table has duplicates of rows

Comment: I'm not native english speaker) Don't understand what it's working fiddle?

Comment: Thank you a lot Gary) I fix it, by erasing main() from body)